# Specifying single method as target for multiple controller URL's

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

There are lots of questions asking about this logic in reverse, however, I can't find an answer for my issue.  I'm new to MVC so might not have the terminology specified correctly.

I have a View containing a form, where a user can request a product.  The same View is used regardless of the product, but specific fields are shown in the form relating to that particular product, e.g.

```
public class RequestController : Controller
{
    // This bit works fine and displays the appropriate form in the view
    public ActionResult MyProduct(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
            return new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }
        ProductRequest qd = new ProductRequest();
        switch (id)
        {
            case "Beer":
                qd.RequestType = Models.RequestType.Beer;
                break;
            case "Coffee":
                qd.RequestType = Models.RequestType.Coffee;
                break;
            case "Soda":
                qd.RequestType = Models.RequestType.Soda;
                break;
        }
        return View("Index", qd);
    }

    // Need to get all forms rendered by the above to post here...
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult MyProduct(ProductRequest qd)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(qd);
        }
        else
        {
            // To do ...
        }
    }
}
```

When the form is rendered in the view, using...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

...the rendered HTML shows a different form target URL for each product type, e.g:

```
<form action="/Request/MyProduct/Beer" method="post">
```

Can I make the `form action` property use the same controller/method regardless of the product type?  e.g.

```
<form action="/Request/MyProduct" method="post">
```

I assume there are different ways to achieve this given the flexibility MVC seems to offer, but I'm looking for best practice please as a learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What added value gives you the `Html.BeginForm` helper over writting the html yourself, apart from preventing you to easily control your action url?

Personally, I have banned most Html helpers usages, there are just getting in my way instead of helping me.

Write your html code yourself, that is frequently even more concise than using html helpers (as illustrated in this [answer](/a/36084660/1178314)).

```html
<form action"@Url.Action("MyProduct", "Request")" method="post">
    @* Add [ValidateAntiForgeryToken, HttpPost] attributes to target action *@
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ...
</form>
```

(And even better, use [UrlHeper extensions](/a/11049853/1178314) to define and centralize your URIs, instead of calling `Url.Action` inside your views or controllers.)

For completeness, I should mention that most input fields html helper extensions (those suffixed with `For`) have the added value of exploiting data-annotations of your view-models. But I consider those annotations as bad practice, because they handle subjects which are not the view-model responsibility in strict MVC pattern. (Display labels? Should be controlled by the view. Validation rules? Should be controlled by the controller. Action argument and/or parameter model? No reason to be bound to the view-model names.)

Comment: Thanks.  `BeginForm` probably gives you no value (I'm only just learning).  I hoped that I would find out how to strongly type controllers and methods into items such as hyperlinks and `.Url.Action` because using a string (IMO) is no better than writing the raw HTML myself.

Comment: About strings in `Url.Action`, precisely. This is why I recommend using UrlHelper extensions instead.

Comment: Extensions you've written yourself, or existing ones?  Just curious to know what's "out there"?

Comment: Follow the link I have put. Extension your write yourself for specifying your urls. Essentially, you define extension method containing the actual call to the url helper, thus allowing you to centralize all magic strings inside one single extension class, instead of spreading/duping them all around your code.

Comment: Since you are asking for some guidance, I have added anti-CSRF protection. It should be there on any form causing some data changes on the server side. See [Owasp](https://www.owasp.org) and its [Top 10 project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) for more information on security threats.

Comment: This answer is just wrong ... put this in a partial view and ajax load it from the client, your validation code on the client won't work because it won't generate your validation attributes without a form context (one of the things the helper you're suggesting to ignore does) ... the reason your answer is shorter is because it's missing a ton of functionality.

Comment: No, you may read again my answer which already address this. Those functionalities are just missing the point of MVC. They are not view model responsibility. Data annotation violates separation of concerns principle. You are free to have your point of view not in accordance with mine, no trouble with that. But stating "wrong" here is over stating.

Comment: The view isn't producing the data annotations, the helpers working with the metadata provider is, separation of concerns is not violated with MVC's base implementation, the helpers allow the complete correct rendering of the html to allow the client framework to behave correctly according to the meta rules, which requires the data annotations. Also the controller's job is not to validate the view model in either a get or a post scenario as this would violate separation of concerns, you should only ask "m.IsValid?" the controller doesn't actually do the validation.

Comment: The point with separation of concerns is not the run time but the design time. Labels to be used are still defined in view model instead of view. And yes, in my cases, I may have to use different labels for the same view model element in the same view. Validation rules get defined in view model, but the same view may have to call different actions with the same model but with different validation rules. And I consider validation is the controller job, eventually with the help of the business layer.

Answer (score 2):

The Html.BeginForm() call accepts various parameters, which can declare the controller/method you wish the form to use.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyProduct", "Request", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
```

Should produce:

```
<form action="/Request/MyProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```